# Mail Form in PHP : syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php, email, variables

I know this is a very commun issue, but as I didn't forget any semicolon, and I declared all variables at the beginning of the script, I'm wondering why this error still throws.

The code is very simple : 
EDIT :

```
if (isset($_POST["email"])) 
{
$name=(isset($_POST["name"])) ? $_POST["name"] : ""; 
$email=(isset($_POST["email"])) ? $_POST["email"] : ""; 
$phone=(isset($_POST["phone"])) ? $_POST["phone"] : ""; 
$ext=(isset($_POST["ext"])) ? $_POST["ext"] : ""; 
$website=(isset($_POST["website"])) ? $_POST["website"] : ""; 
$body=(isset($_POST["body"])) ? $_POST["body"] : ""; 
$to = "romain.petit@infiniscale.com";
$subject = "Message $name from Infiniscale Website";
$message = "$name sent you a message using the contact form. <br/>";
$message .= "Infos : <br/>";
$message .= "Email : $email <br/>";
$message .= "Phone : $phone <br/>";
$message .= "Ext : $ext <br/>";
$message .= "Website : <a href=\"$website\">$website</a> <br/><br/>";
$message .= "Message: $body <br/>";
$from = "mailer@infiniscale.com";
$headers = "From: " .  $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
return "Attempted Mail Send.";
}
else
{
  return false;
}
```

The form is sended, and the "Attempted Mail Send." message showed. But I don't receive any email in my mail box, while I know the mail server is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in your message, so instead of:

```
$message = "Website : <a href="$website">$website</a> <br/><br/>";
```

You would need to do

```
$message = "Website : <a href=\"$website\">$website</a> <br/><br/>";
```

For all parts of the message that contain double quotes.

Comment: yop but before closing the topic by doing so, did you see the edit i made ?

Comment: Check to make sure it's not getting trapped in a spam folder and that PHP has the correct path to the sendmail service.

Answer (score 0):

@Nexerus is correct. Can also use :

```
$message = "Website : <a href='".$website."'>$website</a> <br/><br/>";
```

Comment: It is just a edited answer of Nexerus. You can make a comments on Nexerus' Answer. Try to be honest...

Comment: Nexerus was edited his post later. @Tareq please see the Duke's comments which was "**thanks, this caused the error**". I think Nexerus edit his post then. At first he has only one option. This is not my fault.

Comment: @WalidHossain Please see the above comments. A down vote(-) can destroy your life.

Comment: @Arif Let me give you +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the  header is must be separated by carriage return and new line"\r\n".
and your header like this
$header="From:".$from . "\r\n" ;